# JavaScript function to check for vowels

Tags: javascript, regex, string, contains, string-matching

I know this is a basic questions, but I'm trying to work through a beginner's coding problem and I'm stuck on why this code doesn't work.

This is what I have so far:

```js
const myString = "Testing for vowels";

const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];

function countVowels(myString) {
  let count = 0;


  if (vowels.includes(myString)) {
    count++;
  }

  return count
}

const result = countVowels(myString);

console.log(result);
```

When it logs out, it just stays `0`. Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what it is at this point.  I've set up what vowels are, I think I'm asking that, if the vowels I set in the array are in my string, increase the count, but it's just giving me `0`. I know it must be obvious, but I'm stuck.

I've tried a `for` loop, then I thought it may need to be an `if` statement, now I have that in a function. I haven't been able to get the answer either way, so I don't think I'm properly telling the code what the vowels are, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to check the _characters_, not the whole string. Also think about casing. Try basic debugging, use e.g. https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit, before asking.

Comment: `vowels.includes(myString)` is `false`, as your `vowels` array (`["a","e","i","o","u","y"]`) does not contain `"Testing for vowels"`... You need to check each character individually.

Comment: your `vowes` array does not contain the string `Testing for vowels` and you probably were trying to do the opposite, check if the string `Testing for vowels` contains one or more of the elements present in `vowes` right?

Comment: This is where a simple regular expression might help, as in `/[aeiouy]/`. You can use that to count.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. I didn't realize I wasn't feeding it the actual characters. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: `return [...myString].reduce((prev, chr) => prev + (vowels.includes(chr) ? 1 : 0), 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a for loop in order to check if each character is included in the vowels array like this  :

```
const myString = "Testing for vowels";

const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];


function countVowels(myString) {
  let count = 0;

  for(let i = 0 ;  i < myString.length ; i++) {
    if(vowels.includes(myString[i])) {
      count++ ; 
    }
  }

  return count
}

const result = countVowels(myString);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question (again), but for the vowels.includes(myString[i], is the "i" telling it to go through each character of the string?

Comment: i is the index of the array it gets incremented by 1 each loop in order to access the elements of the vowels array

Answer (score 1):

A simple case-[**i**nsensitive and **g**lobally](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#regular-expressions) flagged [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) like ... `/[aeiou]/gi` ... which within a [character set](https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges) does list all vowels, applied via [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), already does the job. The latter operation either returns an array or the `null` value. Thus, an expression like ...

```
'Testing for vowels'.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0
```

... is all what's needed.

And in order to prevent a `TypeError` in case of a `null` match, where one can not access a `length` property, but still wants to come up with a meaningful result, one might utilize both the [*Optional Chaining Operator / `?.`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the  [*Nullish Coalescing Operator / `??`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

Example code ...

```js
console.log(
  "'Testing for vowels'.match(/[aeiou]/gi) ...",
  'Testing for vowels'.match(/[aeiou]/gi)
);
console.log(
  "''.match(/[aeiou]/gi) ...",
  ''.match(/[aeiou]/gi)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "'Testing for vowels'.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0 ...",
  'Testing for vowels'.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0
);
console.log(
  "''.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0 ...",
  ''.match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The implementation of `countVowels` then is as easy as this ...

```
function countVowels(value) {
  return String(value).match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0;
}
```

... or that ...

```
function countVowels(value) {
  return String(value ?? '').match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0;
}
```

... where the latter could be tested like follows ...

```js
function countVowels(value) {
  return String(value ?? '').match(/[aeiou]/gi)?.length ?? 0;
}

console.log(
  "countVowels('Testing for vowels') ...",
  countVowels('Testing for vowels')
);
console.log(
  "countVowels('') ...",
  countVowels('')
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "countVowels() ...",
  countVowels()
);
console.log(
  "countVowels(null) ...",
  countVowels(null)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  "countVowels('NULL') ...",
  countVowels('NULL')
);
console.log(
  "countVowels('UNDEFINED') ...",
  countVowels('UNDEFINED')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const myString = "Testing for vowels";

const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];

function countVowels(myString) {
  let count = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < myString.length; i++){
    if (vowels.includes(myString.substring(i,i+1))) {
      count++;
    }
   }
  return count
}

const result = countVowels(myString);

console.log(result);
```